# Conditional Attributes that is not boolean in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to generate my own component with checkbox system to know if I need the attribute or not (of type `int` / `float` etc)

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="isMinInt" />
@if (isMinInt == true) {
    <input type="number" @bind="MinInt"/>
}
```

So I would like to replace this `@if`:

```
@if(isMinInt == true) {
    <MyComponent @bind-Value="ValueInt" Min="@MinInt"/>
} else {
    <MyComponent @bind-Value="ValueInt"/>
}
```

by something like

```
<MyComponent @bind-Value="ValueInt" 
             @if(isMinInt == true ? Min="@MinInt" : String.Empty />
```

because I will have many attributes on my component and I would like to make it simplier

**EDIT + Solution**

Now using the `@attributes`:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="isMinInt" />
@if (isMinInt == true) {
   <input type="number" @bind="MinInt" />
}

<MyComponent @bind-Value="ValueInt" @attributes="GetAttributesInt()" />

@code {
    private bool isMinInt = false;
    private int MinInt;

    private IDictionary<string, object> GetAttributesInt() {
       var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() { };
       if (isMinInt)
         dict.Add("Min", MinInt);
       return dict;
    }
}
```

**EDIT + Solution 2**

Now using the `@attributes`:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="isMinInt" />
@if (isMinInt == true) {
   <input type="number" @bind="MinInt" />
}

<MyComponent @bind-Value="ValueInt" @attributes="GetAttributesInt()" />

@code {
    private bool isMinInt = false;
    private int MinInt;

    private IDictionary<string, object> GetAttributesInt() {
       var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() { };
       dict["Min"] = this.isMinInt ? MinInt : Int32.MinValue;
       return dict;
    }
}
```

The reason why I'm using `Int32.MinValue` it's because `MyComponent` correspond to an `<input type="number">` where his `min` is bind to my `MinInt`, so if I use `0` in the place of `Int32.MinValue` it won't allow me to go for negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will have many attributes on my component and I would like to make it simplier

You can't do that directly. However, as a walkaround,  you can use the **`@attributes`** to bind attributes dynamically. For example:

```
<MyComponent @bind-Value="ValueInt" @attributes="@a_dictionary_expression"  />
```

Where `@a_dictionary_expression` is a **C# expression** that can be evaluated at runtime. What's more, you can even create a custom function to calculate the dictionary:

```
<MyComponent @bind-Value="ValueInt" @attributes="getAttributes()"  /gt;

@code {
    ... 
    private IDictionary getAttributes()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary(){};
        if(isMinInt) {
            dict.Add("Min", $"{MinInt}");
        }   // this will introduce a bug, see Edit2 for more details
        return dict ;
    }
}
```

**[Edit]**: Here's a way to render the attributes within a single line

```
<input @bind-Value="ValueInt" @attributes="@(isMinInt? new Dictionary<string,object>{ Min= @Min} : new Dictionary<string,object>{})" />
```

**[Edit2]**

The above code will introduce a bug that the `MyComponent` is not updated correctly. The reason is the parameters of `<MyComponent>` received from previous `@attributes` is not automatically cleared when a new `@attributes` received.

For example,

1. the first time `@attributes` is `{Min=1}`, and it results in a statement:

   ```
   MyComponent.Min=1;
   ```
2. The second time `@attributes` is `{}`, because there's no attribute inside it, it won't assign parameters for it, thus the `MyComponent.Min` remains the same.

To fix that, change the above code as below：

```
private IDictionary<string, object> GetAttributesInt() {
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() { };
    dict["Min"] = this.isMinInt ? MinInt : 0 ;
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error when using custom function: Unable to set property 'Min' on object of type Int32  The error was: Specified cast is not valid. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @yToxide Please change it to `dict.Add("Min", MinInt);`

Comment: Thanks, and how could I remove it if my isMinInt come back to false after ?

Comment: @yToxide You don't have to remove it manually. Every time the data is changed, you should get a new dictionary, thus a new `@attributes`, and finally you'll get a new UI rendered. Always follow the pattern : `Change Data ---> UI Updated`

Comment: it's not working, when i uncheck my checkbox, isMinInt go back to false but my component still keep the value of Min

Comment: @yToxide I just debug and could reproduce a same issue. Sorry, I made a bug in my original code. We need change the code to `dict["Min"] = this.isMinInt ? MinInt : 0 ;`. For more details, please check my updated answer above.

Comment: I just had to replace `0` by `Int32.MinValue` because with 0 it will set Min to 0 and I don't want it, and I can't say `null` because it's `int` and not `Nullable<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple solution and it work, hope this help you too:

```
<input id="@InputId"  aria-labelledby="@(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InputId) ? "this is test" : null)">
```